# ¿Cómo justificar texto de un TextView en Android?

Tags: java, android, string

Lo dicho en la pregunta. ¿Cómo justifico texto de un `TextView` en Android? No me acepta los `layout_gravity` ni `gravity`.

A considerar:

- Sin utilizar `WebView` ni derivados de este.
- Sin utilizar librerías de terceros.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text lo siento :(

Comment: Como comenta Jordi, hasta el día de hoy Android 6.0, no es posible la justificación del texto dentro de un TextView programaticamente ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo utilicé esto que me encontré por ahí:

Creé una clase llamada `JustifyTextView`:

```
public class JustifyTextView extends TextView {

private int mLineY;
private int mViewWidth;

public JustifyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    TextPaint paint = getPaint();
    paint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    paint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
    mViewWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    String text = (String) getText();
    mLineY = 0;
    mLineY += getTextSize();
    Layout layout = getLayout();
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
        int lineStart = layout.getLineStart(i);
        int lineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(i);
        String line = text.substring(lineStart, lineEnd);

        float width = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(text, lineStart, lineEnd, getPaint());
        if (needScale(line)) {
            drawScaledText(canvas, lineStart, line, width);
        } else {
            canvas.drawText(line, 0, mLineY, paint);
        }

        mLineY += getLineHeight();
    }
}

private void drawScaledText(Canvas canvas, int lineStart, String line, float lineWidth) {
    float x = 0;
    if (isFirstLineOfParagraph(lineStart, line)) {
        String blanks = "  ";
        canvas.drawText(blanks, x, mLineY, getPaint());
        float bw = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(blanks, getPaint());
        x += bw;

        line = line.substring(3);
    }

    float d = (mViewWidth - lineWidth) / line.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        String c = String.valueOf(line.charAt(i));
        float cw = StaticLayout.getDesiredWidth(c, getPaint());
        canvas.drawText(c, x, mLineY, getPaint());
        x += cw + d;
    }
}

private boolean isFirstLineOfParagraph(int lineStart, String line) {
    return line.length() > 3 && line.charAt(0) == ' ' && line.charAt(1) == ' ';
}

private boolean needScale(String line) {
    if (line.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return line.charAt(line.length() - 1) != '\n';
    }
}}
```

Al `Textview` que quería justificar le puse esto:

```
   <tu.paquete.app.JustifyTextView style="@style/TextColor"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/credits_description"
        android:id="@+id/premiumCreditsDescTextView"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente no es posible justificar el texto hasta el día de hoy (API 23). He visto que has tratado con

```
android:gravity="right"
```

y

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

En nuestro caso tuvimos que utilizar [una librería de terceros **TextJustify**](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) y en algunos casos usamos código HTML para justificar el texto dentro de un `WebView`.

Comment: Está bien, la librería recomendada para justificar texto (ltr) cuál sería?

Comment: Es https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo dentro de la etiqueta del TextView que quieres justificar `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Recuerda que tienes que tener el `layout_width` en `match_parent`. 
A mí no me apareció justificado en la vista previa, pero cuando lo ejecute en el emulador si apareció justificado. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/tb"
android:text="text"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: Lo hice con la API 22 asi que no creo que te de ningún problema

Answer (score 0):

puedes justificar un texto en un TextView en Android con justificationMode, sirve para API>=26

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:justificationMode="inter_word" />
```