# Justificar texto TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Como puedo justificar el texto de una etiqueta TextView en Android-Studio.
He estado leyendo un hilo que decian que utilizase `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"` pero nada, sigue sin justificar.

También he visto otro hilo que decía que utilizase unas *librerías de github*, pero antes de importar librerías para hacer una cosa tan simple como justificar un texto quería saber si se puede hacer con una simple opción. 
Gracias

Comment: Esto fue respondido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5325/c%C3%B3mo-justificar-texto-de-un-textview-en-android

Answer (score -1):

Diseño XML: declara `WebView` en lugar de `TextView`

```
<WebView
 android:id="@+id/textContent"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Código Java: establecer datos de texto en `WebView`

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textContent);
String text;
text = "<html><body><p align=\"justify\">";
text+= "Este es el texto se justificará cuando se muestre!!!";
text+= "</p></body></html>";
view.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

O use esto:

```
android:gravity="center" 

android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Y asegúrese de usar `android:gravity` y **NO** `android:layout_gravity`.

O solo necesitas hacer esto: [setJustificationMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setJustificationMode(int))

```
textView.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
```

por defecto es `JUSTIFICATION_MODE_NONE`.

> Vea también: Esta biblioteca que le proporcionará una forma de justificar el texto:
>
> - [TextJustify-Android](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android)
> - [Cómo colocar vistas correctamente en diseños](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/) (Traducir del Inglés).

**[Captura de Pantalla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755219/8933039):**

[image: Comparison.png]

Comment: Ese metodo es para la api 26 y yo estoy utilizando la 22

Comment: Ah bueno, debería especificarlo en su pregunta :)

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, soy nuevo en esto. Alguna otra idea para la API 22?

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte He actualizado mi respuesta, agregando esto: `android:gravity="center"` verifique si le funciona.

Comment: de esta forma se me queda centrado pero no justificado.

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: Me lo sigue centrando :(

Comment: @IgnacioBelmonte `android:layout_gravity` : se usa para alinear la vista de texto con respecto al diseño principal. y  `android:gravity` se usa para alinear el texto dentro de la vista de texto.

¿Estás seguro de que estás tratando de justificar el texto dentro de la vista de texto o quieres mover la vista de texto con respecto al diseño principal o estás tratando de lograr ambos?

Comment: Vale, ya lo he conseguido, tenía que alinear la vista de texto con respecto a al diseño principal. Muchísimas gracias por tu atención :)

Comment: **Si alguien vota -1** debería explicar las razones por la que votó negativo, para saber si editar la pregunta, eliminarla o discutir el tema en cuestión.